# Cannot mock grails domain class

Tags: unit-testing, grails, junit, mocking

someone, please, explain why domain class behaves different when is mocked with new MockFor(..)?
I use grails 2.4.1.
I have create domain class GTest:

```
class GTest {
    static constraints = {
    }

    String amethod() {
        return "GTest.amethod"
    }
}
```

And a groovy class DTest:

```
class DTest {

    String amethod() {
        return "DTest.amethod"
    }
}
```

And here a groovy test:

```
class GroovyJUnitTest {

    @Test
    void testDTestAmethod() {
        def mock = new MockFor(DTest)
        mock.demand.amethod {
            return "Mock DTest"
        }

        mock.use {
            def dtest = new DTest()
            // Here dtest.metaClass=groovy.mock.interceptor.MockProxyMetaClass@...
            def ret = dtest.amethod()
            // This assertation successes
            assertEquals "Mock DTest", ret
        }
    }

    @Test
    void testGTestAmethod() {
        def mock = new MockFor(GTest)
        mock.demand.amethod {
            return "Mock GTest"
        }

        mock.use {
            def gtest = new GTest()
            // Here dtest.metaClass=groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass@...
            def ret = gtest.amethod()
            // This assertation fails
            assertEquals "Mock GTest", ret
        }
    }
}
```

So, this question is how should Domain class be mocked programmatically?
Thank you for explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You should annotation your test with `grails.test.mixin.TestFor`.

```
@grails.test.mixin.TestFor(MyDomainClass)
class MyDomainClassTest {
    // ...
}
```

See http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/testing.html#unitTestingDomains for more details.